# Can you analyze this result from address sanitizer

Tags: malloc, address-sanitizer, fuzzing

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBZDK.png)

I ran AFL fuzzer to open source program and I ran the program with the output crash from the fuzzing.

This is the result of address sanitizer but I am not sure what this error actually is.

And where do I have to look in?

I'm also adding the gdb result at first glance.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOG15.png)

Comment: The report tells you the function name, source file name, and line number in the source file. Should not be hard to find the locations in the code.

Comment: Please paste such data into your question (as a code block) instead of linking an off-site image.

Comment: And when catching crashes in a debugger, walk up the call stack until you come to "your" code, don't stay at the library code.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you analyze this result from address sanitizer

The Address Sanitizer told you *exactly* what the problem is and where it is happening:

1. On line 581 of `dact_common.cc` (in function `dact_process_file`), you allocated a 524299 byte block of memory.
2. In `comp_plain_algo()` you `memcpy` into this memory 747621 bytes. That `memcpy` is causing heap buffer overflow that is reported.